# jQuery Map To Retrieve Comma Separated Values Separately

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using multiple text box to insert data into database table. So doing few researches and used online resources to make it work. But stuck into one basic thing, I guess. The issue is with the `jQuery` mapping. Let me share the code here:

```js
//Add row to the table
$('#btnAddRow').on('click', function() {
    var $clone = $('#tblQuesAns tbody tr:last').clone();
    $clone.find('input').val('')
    $('#tblQuesAns tbody').append($clone);
   
});

//Add more rows for option
$('body').on('click', '.addOptions', function() { 
   $(this).parent().append('<div><input  class="txtOptions" type="text" /></div>');
});

//Get text box values
$('#btnGetValues').on('click', function() {
const allData = $('#tblQuesAns tbody tr').map(function() {
  const $row = $(this),
    question = $row.find('.txtQuestion').val(),
    options = $row.find('.txtOptions').map(function() {
      return this.value;
    }).get().join(" ");

  //return {  question,  options };
  alert(question + ' ' + options.replace(/\s+/g, "_"));
}).get();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="btnAddRow" type="button">
    Add Row
</button>

<button id="btnGetValues" type="button">
   Get Values
</button>
<table id="tblQuesAns" border="1">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Question</th>
            <th>Options</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input class="txtQuestion" value="Capital of Englnad" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <input class="txtOptions" value="London" />
                <span class="addOptions">(+)</span>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input class="txtQuestion" value="Current Pandemic" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <input class="txtOptions" value="Corona" />
                <span class="addOptions">(+)</span>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

By default, `jQuery` map uses comma and I tried to remove those by using **replace** method as follows:

```
options.join(' ').replace(/\s+/g, "_")
```

Now I may have options that may contain comma. For example:

```
Question     Options
Question 1   New York
             Jakarta
             London, Paris
             Munich
```

So problem is, the values having space from text boxes also get replaced with the underscore sign **replace(/\s+/g, "_")**. So I get this output:

```
New_York_Jakarta_London,_Paris_Munich
```

But my expected output is this:

```
New York_Jakarta_London, Paris_Munich
```

I tried a different way that works but in this case all the text box values get concatenated:

```
var options = $("input[name*='txtOptions']");
var str = "";

$.each(options, function(i, item) {
  str += $(item).val();
});
```

The problem with the above is, when I've different questions say question 1, question 2, it'll merge all the options to both of them. Though I want specific options for both questions.

Comment: map does not use commas. Array.toString() does. Instead just use a join

Comment: `options = $row.find('.txtOptions').map(function() {
        return this.value;
      }).get().join(" ");`

Comment: But I am getting this output - **Capital of England London_New_York,_Jakarta_London**. Expected - **Capital of England London_New York, Jakarta_London** @mplungjan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```js
//Add row to the table
$('#btnAddRow').on('click', function() {
  var $clone = $('#tblQuesAns tbody tr:last').clone();
  $clone.find('input').val('')
  $('#tblQuesAns tbody').append($clone);

});

//Add more rows for option
$('body').on('click', '.addOptions', function() {
  $(this).parent().append('<div><input  class="txtOptions" type="text" /></div>');
});

//Get text box values
$('#btnGetValues').on('click', function() {
  const allData = $('#tblQuesAns tbody tr').map(function() {
    const $row = $(this),
      question = $row.find('.txtQuestion').val(),
      options = $row.find('.txtOptions').map(function() {
        return this.value;
      }).get().join("_");
     return {question,options}
  }).get()
  const x = allData.map(item => `${item.question}_${item.options}`).join(" ")
  console.log(x)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="btnAddRow" type="button">
    Add Row
</button>

<button id="btnGetValues" type="button">
   Get Values
</button>
<table id="tblQuesAns" border="1">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Question</th>
      <th>Options</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input class="txtQuestion" value="Capital of England" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input class="txtOptions" value="London" />
        <span class="addOptions">(+)</span>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input class="txtQuestion" value="Current Pandemic" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input class="txtOptions" value="Corona" />
        <span class="addOptions">(+)</span>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Exactly @mplungjan. Worked perfectly and thanks a ton.